# Windows 7 : Application cannot write to shared folder - Access denied

Tags: windows-7, samba

I'm having permission issues with an in-house application. This applications has an area where you drag and drop files. When you drag and drop the files, it normally saves the file to a shared folder.

This shared folder is a public folder with permissions 777 and the permitted users/groups have been granted the write permission (via the write list directive). This rules out samba permission issue. Furthermore, the problem only occurs on one machine and effects all users on that machine (with the exception of the administrator account).

All our machines are running BitDefender and I have applied the same policy for all machines but to no avail. I have attempted to disable BitDefender but the problem is still present.

I am suspecting it  a GPO issue or other local security policies on that machine that's causing this problem.

If there's anything else you can suggest, please let me know. Thank you.

Here's a snippet of the Samba log:

> [2015/09/30 11:46:56.105804,  3]
>   smbd/trans2.c:5255(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
>   call_trans2qfilepathinfo . (fnum = -1) level=1005 call=5 total_data=0
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.106228,  3] smbd/process.c:1662(process_smb)
>   Transaction 1377 of length 74 (0 toread) [2015/09/30 11:46:56.106310, 
>   3] smbd/process.c:1467(switch_message)   switch message SMBtrans2 (pid
>   17947) conn 0x7f0ea23243e0 [2015/09/30 11:46:56.106351,  3]
>   smbd/trans2.c:3507(call_trans2qfsinfo)   call_trans2qfsinfo: level =
>   1007 [2015/09/30 11:46:56.106384,  3]
>   smbd/trans2.c:2945(smbd_do_qfsinfo)   smbd_do_qfsinfo: level = 1007
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.106454,  3] lib/sysquotas.c:435(sys_get_quota)
>   sys_get_vfs_quota() failed for mntpath[/] bdev[/dev/md0] qtype[2]
>   id[9005]: Invalid argument [2015/09/30 11:46:56.106518,  3]
>   lib/sysquotas.c:435(sys_get_quota)   sys_get_vfs_quota() failed for
>   mntpath[/] bdev[/dev/md0] qtype[4] id[100]: Invalid argument
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.107545,  3] smbd/process.c:1662(process_smb)
>   Transaction 1378 of length 80 (0 toread) [2015/09/30 11:46:56.107627, 
>   3] smbd/process.c:1467(switch_message)   switch message SMBtrans2 (pid
>   17947) conn 0x7f0ea23243e0 [2015/09/30 11:46:56.107668,  3]
>   smbd/trans2.c:5111(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
>   call_trans2qfilepathinfo: TRANSACT2_QPATHINFO: level = 1004
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.107703,  3] smbd/vfs.c:905(check_reduced_name)
>   check_reduced_name [.] [/home/ngligoroski] [2015/09/30
>   11:46:56.107736,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1039(check_reduced_name)
>   check_reduced_name: . reduced to /home/ngligoroski [2015/09/30
>   11:46:56.107775,  3] smbd/trans2.c:5255(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
>   call_trans2qfilepathinfo . (fnum = -1) level=1004 call=5 total_data=0
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108073,  3] smbd/process.c:1662(process_smb)
>   Transaction 1379 of length 80 (0 toread) [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108155, 
>   3] smbd/process.c:1467(switch_message)   switch message SMBtrans2 (pid
>   17947) conn 0x7f0ea23243e0 [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108196,  3]
>   smbd/trans2.c:5111(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
>   call_trans2qfilepathinfo: TRANSACT2_QPATHINFO: level = 1005
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108231,  3] smbd/vfs.c:905(check_reduced_name)
>   check_reduced_name [.] [/home/ngligoroski] [2015/09/30
>   11:46:56.108264,  3] smbd/vfs.c:1039(check_reduced_name)
>   check_reduced_name: . reduced to /home/ngligoroski [2015/09/30
>   11:46:56.108302,  3] smbd/trans2.c:5255(call_trans2qfilepathinfo)
>   call_trans2qfilepathinfo . (fnum = -1) level=1005 call=5 total_data=0
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108716,  3] smbd/process.c:1662(process_smb)
>   Transaction 1380 of length 74 (0 toread) [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108797, 
>   3] smbd/process.c:1467(switch_message)   switch message SMBtrans2 (pid
>   17947) conn 0x7f0ea23243e0 [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108839,  3]
>   smbd/trans2.c:3507(call_trans2qfsinfo)   call_trans2qfsinfo: level =
>   1007 [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108872,  3]
>   smbd/trans2.c:2945(smbd_do_qfsinfo)   smbd_do_qfsinfo: level = 1007
>   [2015/09/30 11:46:56.108945,  3] lib/sysquotas.c:435(sys_get_quota)
>   sys_get_vfs_quota() failed for mntpath[/] bdev[/dev/md0] qtype[2]
>   id[9005]: Invalid argument [2015/09/30 11:46:56.109013,  3]
>   lib/sysquotas.c:435(sys_get_quota)   sys_get_vfs_quota() failed for
>   mntpath[/] bdev[/dev/md0] qtype[4] id[100]: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0):

Start troubleshooting by checking your samba logs on the server to see what permissions are for the folder when you try to access it. It could be 777 on Linux but Samba may not be translating this properly.

You should get something similar to this:

> 192.168.80.29 (ipv4:192.168.80.29:49475) connect to service sharedisk initially as user domain\koullislp (uid=143999, gid=140999) (pid 17799)
>
> domain\koullislp opened file /path/to/your/files read=Yes write=Yes (numopen=5)

Then make sure your samba config is correct. Example:

```
[smbtest] comment = samba test workspace
path = /sambashare/smbtest
valid users = @g-staff
force group = g-staff 
browseable = yes
writeable = yes 
read only = no 
guest ok = no directory mask = 2770
force directory mode = 2770 
create mask = 2775 force 
create mode = 2775
```

Comment: The reason I say it's not Samba is that a few user who do have issues on this computer does not have issues on other computers. Only this computer has that problem. On the server end, the config file is fine.